# WP8 Centered Image on Map

Tags: windows-phone-8

I wish to put a cross hair on my map object in my Panorama application. I wish for the Cross Hair to be centered and allow the user to move the map around freely. When the user is satisfied, I want to get the lat and long of the center part of the cross hair (which is also the center part of the map).

Any idea how I can do this?

I have added an Ellipse to a MapOver etc but that is a static object and moves a long with the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay the cross over the map and just calculate the location of the center of the map (they both will be the same even when they are only visually related).

Comment: Yep. That's exactly how I was thinking of the implementation too.